# How do I center this Image and Hover Effect?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to HTML and CSS.
Please help me to align the image and hover effect (overlay and text over it) I have used in the code snippet below. I am using FlexBox but kind of it's messing up the alignment may be I'm doing it wrong.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: Grey;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.8s ease;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Overlay Effect</h1>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.freepngimg.com/download/technology/7-2-technology-picture.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="text">Hey Sup!</div>
</div>
```

Here is the codepen [Link](https://codepen.io/vinaygowdas/pen/VxopVa) for same

Comment: The link you provided shows that on hover the 2nd image is placed over the 1st image exactly in the center. It is not clear what you want to change. Describe exactly what the problem is. What don't you like. How you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add margin: 0 auto; to your container class. This will center the container and the image inside of it.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:  center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: Grey;
}

.image {
  
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.8s ease;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Overlay</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Overlay Effect</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.freepngimg.com/download/technology/7-2-technology-picture.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="text">Hey Sup!</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: oh! i just missed that one code... thanks.. just a doubt is it a good practice to do like this or any better way to align things ?

Comment: No problem, it happens to all of us. Well, I always use it for divs or images. Always works  And it's a good practice.

Comment: I found this helpful link which explains well about centering things https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: Thanks. Thats really helpful link.

Comment: You are very welcome! By the way as this website explains about { margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; } my code is the shortcut of this two code, so { margin: 0 auto; } And it makes sense, and easy to remember, because you want to margin-left and right to be centered 

Comment: And if later on you want to { margin-top: 30px;} and also make it centered, you can write { margin: 30px auto;}

Answer (score 0):

You are not using flex properly. I have applied the changes in correct way.

```css
.container {  
  display: flex;
  justify-content:  center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
.container > div {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: Grey;
}

.image {
  
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.8s ease;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container > div:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container > div:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Overlay</title>
</head>
<body>
  

    <h1>Overlay Effect</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div> 
      <img src="http://www.freepngimg.com/download/technology/7-2-technology-picture.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="text">Hey Sup!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes I'm new to FlexBox. I see here you shifted width and position from .container {} to .container > div {} Why is that ?!

Comment: Because thats the correct way to do it according to my knowledge. May be I am wrong, but this is better code according to me :)

Comment: If your implementation would have been correct then justify-content should have center aligned your div itself. But your implementation was wrong as per my experience

Comment: Well I tried as you suggested and hover effect is activating outside container.!

Comment: That was because hover effect was still being applied on container div. I have changed that style also. Please check updated answer.